# Givens rotation algorithm without matrix-matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-solver, sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization

I would like to implement a givenRotation algorithm without having matrix-matrix multiplication. Matrix-vector is fine or just *for* looping. I am to decompose a rectangular *(m+1)xm* Hessenberg matrix.

I found an algorithm [here](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Eweb6140/TopTenAlgorithms/QRUpdate.html) but it appears to be for square matrices.

With matrix-matrix multiplication I have made the following script in python. The main goal is to implement in C++.

```
def rotationCoefficients(a, b):
    
    if (b == 0):
        c = 1
        s = 0
    else:
        if (np.abs(a) > np.abs(b)):
            tan = b/a
            c = 1 / np.sqrt(1 + tan**2)
            s = c*tan
        else:
            cot = a/b
            s = 1/np.sqrt(1 + cot**2)
            c = s*cot
            
    return c, s


def QR_givensRotation(A):
  
    m, n = A.shape

    Q = np.eye(m)
    R = A.copy()
    
    
    for j in np.arange(n):
        for i in np.arange(j+1, m)[::-1]:
            x = R[:,j]          
            c, s = rotationCoefficients(x[i-1], x[i])         
            G = np.eye(m)
            G[i-1 : i+1, i-1 : i+1] = np.array([[c, -s],[s, c]])
            R = G.T @ R
            Q = Q @ G
    return Q, R
```

Does anyone have an algorithm without having matrix-matrix multiplication for applying givens rotation to Hessenberg matrices?

Comment: It would be preferable to calculate sines and cosines directly instead of calculating the tangent first. See [LAPACK working note 148](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn148.pdf) for algorithm example.

Answer (score 4):

To apply the rotations, you're only modifying rows $i$ and $i+1$.  So, you can write $R \gets G^T R$ as $$R[i:i+1, :] \gets G^T[i:i+1, i:i+1] R[i:i+1, :],$$ which is just a $2\times2\times n$ matrix product.  Similarly for $Q$, you can get $$Q[:, i:i+1] \gets Q[:, i:i+1]G[i:i+1, i:i+1].$$

You may want to look at BLAS's `?rot` routines (where `?` is one of `s`,`d`,`c`,`z` depending on your datatype).